# Read text file based on identifier and create another set of text file

Tags: java

I have a text file which i need to read based on identifier and group it and create number of text files. i have used RandomAccessFile, Filereader in my earlier project but i need clue from you to achieve below requirement. i will be able to write the code if i get logic to group the line of records based on General Details.

### Collateral.txt

```
General Details|S|!|!|66T4049|N|
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4049| 3825|
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4049| 3826|
Machinery Details|S|!|!|66T4049|N|
General Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|
Immovable Property Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|
US_CIPD|66T4050|N|S156284|02-01-2013 00:58:50|
General Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|IMUSD|I||| | |
Immovable Property Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|IMUSD|
US locale Immovable Property Details|66T4050|N|
General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|M||| | |
General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|M||| | |
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3827|N|        
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3828|N| 
Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   1|Y|
Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   2|Y|
Inspection Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 1846|N|
Inspection Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 1845|N|
Ownership and Tenancy Details|66T4051|  329|0
Ownership and Tenancy Details|66T4051|  328|0
```

Machinery Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|123|55|
Additional Collateral Details|66T4051|N|01|__14P|

General Details is the parent key. under general details, based on condition charge details, Machinary details , Insurance details and other details will be included.

I need to group one general details section and create new file. lets say.

```
Collateral1.txt
General Details|S|!|!|66T4049|N|
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4049| 3825|
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4049| 3826|
Machinery Details|S|!|!|66T4049|N|


Collateral2.txt
General Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|
Immovable Property Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|
US_CIPD|66T4050|N|S156284|02-01-2013 00:58:50|


Collateral3.txt
General Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|IMUSD|I||| | |
Immovable Property Details|S|!|!|66T4050|N|IMUSD|
US locale Immovable Property Details|66T4050|N|


Collateral4.txt
General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|M||| | |
```

and so on...

please help me out which file reader i need to go for and how i can implement the logic. delimiter will be pipe for each column and delimiter will be end line for each row.

Comment: I don't understand the criteria for splitting - in your sample files, both Collateral1.txt and Collateral2.txt have multiple GeneralDetails lines.

Comment: sorry for the confusion which happened because of wrong input. i modified and given proper input now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like you just need to start a new file when you see a line starting with a particular string. That sounds easy:

```
String prefix = "GeneralDetails|"; // Or whatever you want it to be
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("input.txt"), "UTF-8")); // Specify the charset here
try {
    int outputIndex = 0;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine() != null) {
            // Check whether we need to start a new file, closing the old one.
            if (writer == null || line.startsWith(prefix)) {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
                outputIndex++;
                string path = "Collateral " + outputIndex + ".txt";
                // Specify the output encoding here
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(path), "UTF-8")); 
            }
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        } else {
        }
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Wow. it works cleverly.thanks a lot :) i m very glad to get chance to interact with legend people here. i m learning every day new new things because of people who are eagerly waiting to teach us from stackover flow.

Answer (score 1):

One idea to do this can be:

1) Read your source file line by line. 
2) Extract key from this line 
3) Use a map to store key (extracted above) and value as reference to file for this key.
4) Search for key in the map and get the file reference 
   if match found add the above line to this file.
   else create a new file, add this line to this newly created file, put the key and this file reference in map for next usage.
5) Continue above till you reach to end of your file.
6) Close all the files created

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I see no reason to use a map here. If we just need to start a new file each time we see a particular prefix, we don't need to remember anything other than the line we've just read...

Comment: thanks Alankar. you tried to help me out. really i m thankful to you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are correct, no map is required if we want to create a new file on every encounter of same prefix, Map is required only if, same kind of data[based on prefix] needed to be grouped in a single file.

Comment: @user2057006 I am glad that its of some use to you :)